# Purge Layers from QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have created numerous databases from a base source and merely added and removed various layers then saved as a new project. There were more layers common than not in common in each project.

However as i am now branching in QGIS Cloud for some reason in the upload panel it is saying there are layers there that are not in the layers panel.

Is there a purge function (similar to that of autocad).

This question is essentially the same as [Seeking purge function to remove layers from qgs file which are not present in Layers pane of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/layers-in-qgs-file-not-present-in-the-layers-pane)