# QGIS layers not adding properly

Tags: qgis, layers

using QGIS 1.8.0 lisboa on windows 7 pc

adding vector layers and they are not adding properly they don't show up in the layers list but they are there when I happen to merge the the layers altogether, I can see them listed, they are not hidden.

it seems to happen when i try to add layers and have control layer render order on, because when i turn it off the layers adds fine, but i cannot delete the previous layer that didn't add correctly, i can't see them to select and remove them

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what is wrong - please upload a screenshot which shows the problematic behavior somewhere on the web (e.g. on http://imgur.com/) and post the link here.

Comment: there is nothing to see, simply i add vector layers but they don't add properly, they are there but i can't access them

Comment: http://imgur.com/gkjklPH

Comment: Please specify exactly, where you see and don't see the layers (TOC (legend), map canvas, dbf...) please also describe what you tried, and what you would expect to happen.

Comment: ^ "they don't show up in the layers list" ^ or anywhere else except when i use the mmqgis plugin to merge all layers they are are listed there.

Comment: QGIS 1.8 works well on Windows7 and the image you link to shows the layers list populated with a lot of vector layers - so clearly some layers are added correctly - and therefore your statement of the problem is an over generalisation.  This is why we don't understand what problem you are experiencing.  If the layer 204020203b is the red feature in the center of the screen, then the layer you highlight (204020203) would normally be underneath it (and if identical, then obscured by the one above). Is what you are alluding to?  An image clearly demonstrating the discrepancies is needed.

Comment: no that is not what Im alluding to, I can't show you something that doesn't appear, i add a vector layer and it doesn't appear in the list, (or anywhere else.) but it was added because when I use merge all layers its listed.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nuSANEH.jpg a layer called 204020203 is listed three times when I go to use the merge plugin, which highlights that the layers did not add properly as they are not listed in the layer menu

Comment: Can you share the problematic file? I think otherwise we might be stuck here. My theory currently would be that the file is corrupted.

Comment: here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6AEiinGYynOdEEwcDNQX1EwVUU/edit?usp=sharing the problem with that is this is about the third seperate time i've done this and it keeps happening https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6AEiinGYynOdEEwcDNQX1EwVUU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I wonder if your QGIS project file has become corrupted in some way.  I have just this moment had a surprisingly similar thing happen to me using QGIS 1.9.  I could add the vector layer and it appears in the TOC but not on screen.  In fact adding it 'turned off' other layers.  Like you they were listed but not visible.  There was nothing wrong with the data and QGIS works fine normally.  Therefore, the only logical option is that the project file has become corrupted.  Sadly we don't have the equivalent of an MXD doctor, so I rebuilt the project manually and everything works fine.

Comment: this actually seems like the same problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/is-there-a-purge-function-to-remove-layers-from-a-qgs-file-which-are-not-present