# Deleted layers still appear while loading project in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers

I'm working on a project where I digitized a few maps (georeferenced) and I also added a couple of csv files. I deleted the raster and cvs layers after I included them into the project as shapefiles but when I re-load the project to continue working on it these phantom layers still appear in the layer panel until the project is actually loaded and ready to work.
It doesn't make any problem other than these layers being listed as options to choose, for instance doing interpolation or other spatial options. The problem occurs when I delete the original csv file from the original location, even though it is not visible in the layer panel. If I do that, QGIS closes with error immediately after opening. I cannot move the csv or raster files from the folder they were originally saved because I cannot load the project.

Same thing was discussed in [qgis.org](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7086) but the discussion was closed apparently because it was solved, which is not my case. Any clues?

Windows Vista - QGIS Lisboa 1.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar question here: [Is there a purge function to remove layers from a qgs file which are not present in the Layers pane?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/is-there-a-purge-function-to-remove-layers-from-a-qgs-file-which-are-not-present/58743?noredirect=1#comment77872_58743)

it worked for me and removes the empty layers.

Hope it helps.