# Remove layers in memory QGIS python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a plugin with my own map canvas and I create a button in order to remove all the layers visible or opened in map canvas.
I use this lines:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
self.canvas.refresh()
```

And it works but I noted that the layers are not in canvas but exist even that, I think they are in memory. How can I permanently remove the layers?

Comment: How are you suspecting they are still in memory, can you expand more about this?

Comment: The layers are removed of visual field, but when I use self.canvas.layerCount() to count the number of layers in canvas, they still give me the number of layers that I removed.

Comment: They are perhaps still stored within the layer registry. This post might help in _purging_ the removed layers: [Is there a purge function to remove layers from a qgs file which are not present in the Layers pane?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/is-there-a-purge-function-to-remove-layers-from-a-qgs-file-which-are-not-present)

Comment: When I add a layer using QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layerName) method and remove it using QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers() I get a count of 0.  How are you adding your layers?  Is the returned count for all the layers that were there before or just one or two?

Comment: Yes I am using QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer) and then self.canvas.setExtent(rlayer.extent()) but when I try to remove, it removes the map but the count is never 0. The count is the number of layers that were added.

Comment: The methods suggested by Joseph doesn't work for me. I think that map canvas is not refreshed even I have also that defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
I could not to change the result obtained by `self.canvas.layerCount()` but if I use `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().count()` I get 0 if the layers are removed. So it is what I need.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've asked quite a lot of questions but barely accepted any. Did none of the answers helped? You can atleast accept your own answers.