# Purge function to remove layers from a qgs file which are not present in the Layers pane using QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

My QGIS3 projects tend to keep older versions of layers in the registry even after removing from the legend.

This is the same question as the one in:
[Is there a purge function to remove layers from a qgs file which are not present in the Layers pane?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/is-there-a-purge-function-to-remove-layers-from-a-qgs-file-which-are-not-present?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The solution proposed by Matthias Kuhn still works in QGIS 2.18.16 but when trying the master build of QGIS3, the python script proposed doesn't work anymore due to API changes in QGIS3. Is there a way in QGIS3 to remove these "ghost layers" from the registry like in QGIS 2.18.16?

Comment: It is OK to link to another question as background but every question here is expected to be standalone so please write out precisely what you wish to ask, including what you have tried and where you are stuck within your question body.

Comment: Do these "ghost layers" still exist when you save as a new project?

Comment: Yes they do. If i click Project -> Save as and give a new name, the ghost layers still appear in the project's "Identify layers" panel of Project properties and in layer lists when using processes process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [QGIS Backwards Incompatible Changes](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html), the `QgsMapLayerRegistry` has been moved to the [QgsProject class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html).

Therefore a number of methods which used:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
```

should be replaced with:

```
QgsProject.instance()
```

---

So the QGIS 3 equivalent of the answer from the post you linked to could be:

```
registryLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().keys()
legendLayers = [ layer.layerId() for layer in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers() ]
layersToRemove = set( registryLayers ) - set( legendLayers )
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers( list( layersToRemove ) )
```

Comment: @N.McFadden - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)